# Windows form resized at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface, autoscalemode

I am having a problem with my Visual Studio. Form always change its size at runtime.

The form's size when designed is 1732; 1005 as shown in the figure below:

[image]

But when I run the program, the form's size changes to a smaller size (new size: 868;491) as shown below:
[image]

I already tried changing the DPI and the resolution of the PC that I am using but it's still the same. What will I change to get the actual size of the designed UI at runtime?

Comment: try setting your form's `MinimumSize` and see if it helps, if it does, you probably have set `AutoSize` to `true`

Comment: @am05mhz I already tried setting the `MinimumSize` but it's still the same. I also checked the `AutoSize` property and it's set to false.

Comment: hmm, that is odd indeed, are you using a hires monitor?

Comment: Yah. My current resolution is 1920x1080. I also tried using other resolutions but that didn't help.

Comment: Typical Windows 10 question.  It assumes that every program today is dpiAware, Visual Studio and the Winforms designer certainly are, it is just programmers that are not.  You get a very early preview of what your program will look like on an old machine.  Just tell Windows that [you are dpiAware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034) and you can ignore it for a while longer.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting "AutoScaleMode" on the form to "None".  I found my form was set to mode "Font".  After I changed the font size on a few GUI components, the form's layout was far different at run time from what I saw in the designer.  After setting the scale mode to "None", the form looked great at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting FormBorderStyle to FixedDialog or something related to Fixed****. Also you can try setting MinimumSize and MaximumSize to 1732; 1005.

Comment: you can set the formborderstyle at runtime from code too.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that the forms `AutoSize = true` and `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`?
Then change AutoSize to false or set AutoSizeMode to GrowOnly